# How to set default value for @Html.EditorFor(model => model.location)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, model, default-value

i tried to add , new { @Value = "test" } but failed.

then i modify the model to

```
    private string _location = string.Empty;

    public string location { get { return _location; } set { _location = value; } }
```

or even change the string.empty into my default text, still failed.

any idea ? Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is good, it should work. But as it does not, i think you are passing null model  to your view - in this case it never gets to evaluating location, its null. Try passing non null model to  your view.

```
return View(new LocationViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

tryed your solution with the following source and it works fine for me.

Model

```
public class LocationViewModel
{
    private string _location = "test";

    public string Location
    {
        get { return _location; }
        set { _location = value; }
    }
}
```

Action

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        return View(new LocationViewModel());
    }
```

View

```
@model LocationViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Test</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```